# When alternator bolts slackened it starts putting out a proper voltage. Relay 2.2hdi

Tags: electrical, alternator, citroen, belt, serpentine-belt

I've had some alternator woes over the past week.

Citroen Relay model II 2005 - 2.2hdi.

My alternator wasn't putting out anything:

- Battery was down to 11.5v
- Checked the alternator with a multimeter (same voltage as battery when engine on)
- No bad sounds from the aux belt and belt feels newish and tight
- No real trouble starting or turning over (despite the low voltage battery)

The old alternator was only about 10000 miles old.
I figured the alternator's voltage reg had blown, instead of just replacing the reg I just got a whole new alternator (no time etc..).

I installed the new alternator with 3 of the bolts loosely on (not torqued all the way), and turned on the engine. It started putting out 13.5v, not perfect, but that's a lot better than what I had before.
So next I finish the mounting and install all the bolts properly. It starts only putting out 12.5v.

- The old battery was dead, so I installed a new battery.
- I checked the D+ battery light cable with a multimeter, it's putting out about 11.5v when ignition is on, I make sure it's clean and seated properly.
- Re-checked all the alternator cabling, no voltage drop issues I could see.
- re-seated the aux belt, make sure it's tightening properly when running. (listening to the alternator maybe it makes a light kind of "Geary" sound when running, but only when I go right up close.) No wobbling, no squealing, again belt seems tight and newish.
- Remove any other components that might be parasitically draining the battery

Still only putting out 12.5v.

***Then as a last resort I try slackening the bolts right loose again on the alternator***

Suddenly putting out over 13v again (range 13.2 to 13.5).

*My hunch is that the tensioner isn't doing its job properly*, and that slackening the bolts puts a tighter angle on the belt so it starts driving the alternator properly. This would also explain the range and the fact that it doesn't seem to be full voltage (14v)

I feel like I've eliminated every other possibility, apart from maybe the bad luck of getting another duff alternator?

Is there anything else it could be, or I should try? It's a strange one because the belt seems almost new.

I've taken a video of the belt and will post a link later.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!